# Writing a script in Unix to see if a file exist and to show its content

Tags: variables, unix

I'm writing a program in Unix to have the user enter in the file they would like to view the contents on but i'm stuck and dont know way i keep getting error.

the errors i keep getting are :unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
and the other is: Syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
# this program allows the user to see the contents of a file
echo
clear
echo
echo "Enter in the the file you would like to see: "
read $1
if [ ! -e "$1" ]
 then
  echo cat /export/home/cna397/logname/$1
 else
  echo "This file does not exist

fi
```

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to the rescue!

Comment: thank you i found why i was getting the erroe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is the executable (without errors) version of what you wrote, now continue with a better basis, if you still have questions just update this post with code  plus comments, or just make a new one.

```
echo "Enter in the the file you would like to see:"
read file_name
if test ! = $file_name
    then
    echo $(cat /export/home/cna397/logname/$file_name)
else
    echo "This file does not exist"
fi
```

**P.S** if on the if test you are checking strings, keep the equal (=) i put....

Comment: What's `if test ! = $file_name` supposed to do?

Comment: its ur code actually, you should use the test between two "strings" to check if their names are the same, so if instead of ! you add the name of the file you want to check if it exists then if its true it will go in the if state.

Comment: I'm not OP :) I asked because I don't think `if test ! = $file_name` checks if the file exists and I don't see any other file names to compare `$file_name` with so... ?

Comment: man i just took the code that he posted and fixed it so it wont have errors, i suppose that in the place of ! he will add something else that he has in mind so that the output works for him as he wants it to.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an ending double quote here:

```
echo "This file does not exist
```

`$1` is for commandline arguments. You'll need something like this if you want the user to enter a filename *while* the script is running:

```
read filename
echo $(cat "/export/home/cna397/logname/$filename")
```

Comment: i tried that but now the program continues to say this file does not exist

Comment: @MosesSaygbe Yeah, you can't just use it like a drop-in replacement for what you have. I simply corrected the syntax error and wrote the two lines that enable the user to enter a filename as opposed to passing the filename via the command line. What's do you want `if [ ! -e "$1" ]` to do?

Comment: @MosesSaygbe `cat` will tell you if the file doesn't exist btw. It's not really necessary to  check whether or not the file exists *before* you `cat` it (if that's what you're trying to do)